# Python to track links in CSV file

Tags: python, csv, hyperlink

I have CSV file with some links stored in one of the columns. Also I have some other Data in same CSV file. I want to read only links that contain `'https:'` and print them out. Can you please help?

```
import csv
filename ='abc.csv'
with open(filename,'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    try:
        for row in reader:
            if 'http:' in reader:
                print(row)
```

Comment: Show us some sample input and the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you do not know what column the links are in you could try this (just a minor modification in your code):

```
for row in reader:
    for item in row:
        if item.startswith('http'):
            print(item)
```

Comment: Output: line 8, in <module>
    for row in reader:
ValueError: readline of closed file . Did i do any thing wrong. I following same Instruction.

Comment: Finally code is running indentation was creating huddle figured out. But when running code there is no print value. 
        for item in row:
            if item.startswith('https:'):
                print(item)